# How do I enable mcrypt for php 5.6 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apache2, php, php-fpm

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with a website that requires PHP 5.6. But on installing the website script I get the error:

```
mcrypt is not enabled on your web hosting account
```

To install `mcrypt`, I used:

```
sudo apt install php5.6-mcrypt
```

But in the php info it isn't enabled.
I tried `phpenmod mcrypt`, and I get warnings similar to this:

```
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.0/mods-available
```

I haven't installed mcrypt on these versions of PHP so they are not required.

However nothing seems to kick php5.6 mcrypt into gear.

I tried adding the lines below to the `php.ini` which again doesn't solve the problem.

```
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

Any ideas how to get mcrypt working for php5.6.

I am using `php5.6-fpm` and have added that to the virtualhost so php5.6 is being loaded for the sdomain.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

```
inkspot@vps:~$ sudo apt install php5.6-mcrypt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
php5.6-mcrypt is already the newest version (5.6.40-68+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.or g+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

inkspot@vps:~$ sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
Considering dependency proxy for proxy_fcgi:
Module proxy already enabled
Module proxy_fcgi already enabled

inkspot@vps:~$ sudo a2enmod setenvif
Module setenvif already enabled

inkspot@vps:~$ sudo a2enconf php5.6-fpm
Enabling conf php5.6-fpm.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl reload apache2
  
inkspot@vps:~$ sudo phpenmod mcrypt
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available

inkspot@vps:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
inkspot@vps:~$ sudo service php5.6-fpm restart
inkspot@vps:~$
```

here are the reults of: sudo apache2ctl -M

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 security2_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
```

Comment: Unless you've added custom sources, PHP 5.6 is **not available** for Ubuntu 22.04.  Did you add an extra PPA or such?  Note that it looks like you haven't installed the corresponding mcrypt scripts.  Unless you need PHP 5.6 (which is OBSOLETE and INSECURE), you should be using newer PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have told me so far, you probably have some old config file making problems. You mentioned you kept an old `php.ini`. In such case it will be best to purge all `php5.6` packages and delete their configs.

```
sudo apt purge php5.6*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/php/5.6/
```

On Ubuntu 22.04, the default PHP version is 8.2.

To install `php5.6-fpm` on Ubuntu 22.04, first you will need to add the `ppa:ondrej/php` repository, because `php5.6` package is not in the official repo.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Install php5.6 packages:

```
sudo apt install php5.6
sudo apt install php5.6-fpm
sudo apt install php5.6-mcrypt
```

To enable php5.6-fpm on a specific site, you have to edit site's virtualhost file (the default is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`). Between `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `</VirtualHost>`, add the following code:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

Enable the modules and configs:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
sudo a2enmod setenvif
sudo a2enconf php5.6-fpm
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

Restart the Apache and don't forget to restart the FPM too:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service php5.6-fpm restart
```

(Optional) If you want, you can disable `php8.2` and replace the default PHP version for the Apache server with `php5.6-fpm` by doing this:

```
sudo a2dismod php8.2
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_event
sudo a2enconf php5.6-fpm

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hio, thanks @sotirov I will give some of that a go. But I already tried most of it. php is up and running for the website. I just cant install and get mcrypt working.

Comment: I've tested it on one of my servers, so it works if you follow the sequence of the commands. Please, share more details if some of the steps doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks @sotirov I followed some of those commands and added the results to the main post underneath ADDTIONAL INFORMATION. And the result is that mcrypt isnt active in the info.php. Theres just 2 instances of the text mcrypr in the page. In other words, the mod is installed but not loading.

Comment: What version of PHP is loaded? How are you checking it? Have you done some changes to `/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini`? Can you share the result of `sudo apache2ctl -M`?

Comment: Thanks @sotirov I have added the results in the post. PHP Version 5.6.40-68+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is loaded. For that site. Im using different (fpm) versions for different sites. mcrypt is working in other versions (7.4 upward). I am visiting the info.php page to check it. I previously had 5.6 installed on Ubuntu 2018 and copied the working ini file from there. But I only did that after trying the default version.

Comment: @Hawk007 Just updated my answer with new instructions how to do some clean up.

Comment: TThanks @satirov I will give this a go over the next day or so. Much appreciated for the assistance.